# Codeigniter comparing id of value greater or smaller then the same field

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter to form a simple query that is not working correctly.

I am trying to get a field where the `action_ id` is greater than one but less than 4.

Example as below:

`$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action >', '1');`

`$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action <', '4');`

However I am not sure if because I am referencing the same fields twice , CodeIgniter does not know how to run the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action >', 1);

$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action <', 4);
```

Or, if where condition have static value, you can directly do as:

```
$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action > 1');

$this->db->where('newsfeeds.action < 4');
```

And see the query using:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give those conditions in an array and pass them through get_where function

Check this
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple condition in `$this->db->where` like

```
$where= array('newsfeeds.action >' =>1, 'newsfeeds.action <' => 4)
$this->db->where($where);
```

See this for reference [Active Record](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this one send the sql to he function.

> `$this->db->query($sql);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by making a string that contain whole WHERE condition like

```
$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Hope this will help.